# Failed to install RcppArmadillo on Linux with OpenMP Error

Tags: r, c++11, redhat, rcpp, rcpparmadillo

I tried to install RcppArmadillo on a school Linux Hyper Cluster (which I do not have sudo access). I am installing via:

```
install.packages('RcppArmadillo')
```

in the R interface. The installation failed with the following error message:

```
using C++ compiler: ‘g++ (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44)’
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/home/yz909/R/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include -I'/cache/home/yz909/R/lib64/R/library/Rcpp/include' -I/usr/local/include   -fopenmp -fpic  -g -O2  -c RcppArmadillo.cpp -o RcppArmadillo.o
RcppArmadillo.cpp: In function ‘int armadillo_get_number_of_omp_threads()’:
RcppArmadillo.cpp:103:32: error: ‘omp_get_max_threads’ was not declared in this scope
     return omp_get_max_threads();
                                ^
RcppArmadillo.cpp: In function ‘void armadillo_set_number_of_omp_threads(int)’:
RcppArmadillo.cpp:113:26: error: ‘omp_set_num_threads’ was not declared in this scope
     omp_set_num_threads(n);
                          ^
make: *** [RcppArmadillo.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘RcppArmadillo’
* removing ‘/cache/home/yz909/R/lib64/R/library/RcppArmadillo’

The downloaded source packages are in
        ‘/tmp/Rtmpk3pNYK/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("RcppArmadillo") :
  installation of package ‘RcppArmadillo’ had non-zero exit status
```

It seems to be a complier issue, could anyone help me with it?

I've tried both installing directly using

```
install.packages('RcppArmadillo')
```

and install using the github link, both yield to the same issue. My current R version is 4.3.1 and Rcpp version is 1.0.11.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, and Rcpp(Armadillo).  You can search past questions here (and open/closed issues at GitHub).  I think your question has been asked a few times already:  g++ 4.8.* is simply too old.  Try installing an older RcppArmadillo version from the [archive directory](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/RcppArmadillo/). Else you need to compile as C++11 (or newer) and you are adviced to use at least g++-8 or g++-10.  (The current version is g++-13). On RedHat (and alike) you can get newer version via an add-on called 'devtoolset`. Good luck!

Comment: The immediate error is also that R thinks you should have OpenMP, but do not. See if OpenMP can be installed on your cluster, it will make a few operations faster. If you can't then hand-edit the `src/Makevars` to no use `-fopenmp` in the compile and link step. _Maybe_ you get lucky with g++-4.8 but I am doubtful.

Comment: In console not in R try `sudo apt install r-cran-rcpparmadillo -y`.

Comment: @jay.sf: Not on RedHat which is what OP uses.

Comment: Ah no apt in RedHat right. OP might try `sudo yum groupinstall "Development Tools"` which should include latest g++.

Comment: thx, Apt is not available, I probably need to ask the Admin since I am not sudoer

Comment: @YuzeZhou No, `apt` is for Debian / Ubuntu.  Your tool is `yum` or `dnf` but you also already said you cannot do `sudo` so Jay was wrong twice.  Happens to the best of us :grin:

Comment: This issue is a cross-post (which is generally discouraged) from [GitHub issue #427](https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppArmadillo/issues/427).

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Not really discouraged since GitHub isn't part of SE. OP can at least email a summary to the school's IT folks now :)

Comment: Thanks Dirk! It seems like updating will be a better option, as I am migrating C++11 work to that cluster with old compilers.

Comment: @jay.sf Well in my role of Rcpp support personal I happen to strongly discourage redundant crosspostings on any combination of mailing lists, social media, stackoverflow and github. Better to have one focussed discussion in one place only. 
 Most package authors / maintainers I talk to second that view. But you are more than welcome to repeat yourself in all places.  I just happen to find that inefficient.  I don't speak for SO so no risk mistaking my grumblings with anything resembling anything official.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Thanks for clarifying and thanks for GitHub link where the issue is in best hands.